# chartWrapper of dataView of dataTable created by data.join not updating on value change

Tags: google-visualization

First, please pardon the novel below, but this is fairly hard to describe.

I have a fairly complex application that I'm working on at the moment using gviz through HtmlService of a GAS application.

This is more of a client side gviz API question though.

I'm loading 2 data tables through the query method and combining them through data.join.  This resulting dataTable is the source for a data view.

The view is then used to generate a dashboard with multiple category filters and a single tableChart.  I have a button which toggles between two filter sets for both the view rows and columns displayed.  The concept is to load all records and toggle between pending and completed showing the relevant columns to the user.

This part is actually working perfectly well.  The issue that I have is a data update issue.  Every time the visualisation draws, I iterate through the resulting table and attach actions to various columns.

One such action opens a jQueryUI dialog with the rows values and allows the user to make modifications and submit to the server.  When it submits, rather than re-querying my data, my approach is to update the dataTable on AJAX success which is much much faster.

Prior to implementing the join, this was based on a single dataTable and when I updated the dataTable, the dataView based on it would update as well and calling draw() on the chartWrapper would update the UI just as expected.

Trouble is that this isn't working on the joined dataTable.  I have confirmed in developer tools on the client side that the dataTable is in fact updating the values as is the dataView, but this never propagates to the tableChart.

And here's the really strange part.  If use the .getDataTable method of the chartWrapper in dev tools, I can confirm that the record in question **is updated!**  Though the value in the generated visualisation **is not**.

I've tried redrawing the chartWrapper in my AJAX success to no avail.  It does redraw (chartWrapper) as the scroll level changes, but data does not change.  I've tried manually redrawing both the chartWrapper and dashboard in dev tools even passing the view as the dataTable.  Both do in fact redraw, but neither updates the data.

I've tried redrawing the getDataTable table on the chartWrapper, but that basically disassociates from my dashboard and styles and draws the entire dataset which is not what I need.

Changing the category filters doesn't update the tableChart after filtering back.  Even applying the different filters to the dataView and then back doesn't update it.  The only way I've found that works is to re-query the entire thing which takes a good 5-10 seconds.  An unacceptable delay for every single change.  This is fine when first loading, but ideally that should only happen once per user session.

I've spent hours debugging and scouring the (terrible) documentation and everything I've seen seems to indicate that it should work.

I'm starting to wonder if maybe this is some sort of cache issue or if I'm missing some trick that's not explained in the documentation.

The client side code for this particular page is 1100 lines, so hard to post in full.  Below is an extremely simplified version of what I'm doing with the key parts included.  Would appreciate any advice or suggestions.

Note, I've omitted quite a few parts related to generating the dialog or buttons for the actions, but they are mostly irrelevant.

```
var loaded = false;
var ready = {pro: false, sec: false};
var data = {};

    // Ajax load gviz api
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback',
      cache: true,
      dataType: 'script',
      success: function(){
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], 'callback' : sendQuery
        });
        return true;
      }
    });
    function sendQuery() {
        console.log('query setting');
        var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};

        var urlPro = 'Google Spreadsheet source 1';
        queryPro = new google.visualization.Query(urlPro, opts);
        queryPro.setQuery('select A,B,C,D,E where(G = \'No\')');//...15k+ rows 30+ cols in reality

        var urlSec = 'Google Spreadsheet source 2';
        querySec = new google.visualization.Query(urlSec, opts);
        querySec.setQuery('select A,B,C,D');//...~200+ rows 30+ cols in reality, rows created with app

        queryPro.send(function(response){
            console.log('query Pro returned');
            if (response.isError()) {
                alert('Error in query Pro: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
            }
            ready.pro = true;
            data.pro = response.getDataTable();
            if (ready.pro && ready.sec) {
                drawDashboard(false);
            }
        });
        querySec.send(function(response){
            if (response.isError()) {
                alert('Error in query Sec: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
            }
            console.log('query Sec returned');
            ready.sec = true;
            data.sec = response.getDataTable();
            if (ready.pro && ready.sec) {
                drawDashboard(false);
            }
        });

    }

    function drawDashboard(complete) {
      var pendingCols = [0,2,3,4];
      var completeCols = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8];

      if (!loaded) {
          console.log('first load of data');

          var joinProCols=[1,2,3,4];
          var joinSecCols=[1,2,3];

          joined = new google.visualization.data.join(data.pro, data.sec, 'left', [[0, 0]], joinProCols, joinSecCols);

          viewActive = new google.visualization.DataView(joined);

          var numCols = joined.getNumberOfColumns();
          for (var i=0; i<numCols; i++){
            ogColName = joined.getColumnLabel(i).replace(/\W/g, '');
            if (empTable.hasOwnProperty(ogColName)){ //passed from server; ommitted def in this example
                joined.setColumnLabel(i, empTable[ogColName][lang]);
            }
            joined.setColumnProperty(i, 'ident', ogColName);
          }

      }

      var pendingRows = joined.getFilteredRows([{column: 4, value: null}]);
      var completeRows = joined.getFilteredRows([{column: 4, minValue: ''}]);

      if (complete) {
          viewActive.setColumns(completeCols);
          viewActive.setRows(completeRows);
      } else {
          viewActive.setColumns(pendingCols);
          viewActive.setRows(pendingRows);
      }

      dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard-div'));

      // options for displayed table
      var tableOpts = { 
        width: '1500px',
        height: '100%', 
        page: 'enable', 
        pageSize: 40,
        cssClassNames: {
          headerCell: 'gviz header',
          headerRow: 'gviz header',
          oddTableRow: 'gviz odd',
          tableRow: 'gviz even',
          selectedTableRow: 'gviz selected',
          hoverTableRow: 'gviz hover',
          rowNumberCell: 'gviz rowNum'
        }
      };

      tableChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'table-div',
        'options': tableOpts
      });

      var picker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'sel-pick1',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Picker1',
            'ui': {
              'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
              'caption': 'Picker1'
            }
          }
        });
      var picker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'sel-pick2',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Picker2',
            'ui': {
              'labelStacking': 'vertical',
              'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
              'caption': 'Picker2'
            }
          }
        });
      //...quite a few more pickers in real code
      if (complete) {

          var picker3 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'sel-pick3',
            'options': {
              'filterColumnLabel': 'picker3',
              'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
                'caption': 'picker3'
              }
            }
          });
          //...A couple more pickers in real app here too
      }
      // Set up dependencies between controls and charts
      dashboard.bind(picker1, picker2);
      //...bindings for other pickers
      if (complete) {
          dashboard.bind(picker2, picker3);
          dashboard.bind([picker1, picker2, picker3], tableChart);
      } else {
          dashboard.bind([picker1, picker2], tableChart);
      }
      // Draw all visualization components of the dashboard and add listeners

      google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart, 'ready', function(){
        google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart.getChart(), 'page', addFields);
        google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart.getChart(), 'sort', addFields);
        google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart.getChart(), 'select', function(e){
            //cancel selection here as it won't be useful
            tableChart.getChart().setSelection('');
        });
        //grab the table and inject our custom actions into it
        if (complete) {
            addFields(true);
        } else {
            addFields();
        }
        // show containers
        $('.processing.page').hide();
        $('#dashboard-div').show();
        loaded = true;

      });


      dashboard.draw(viewActive);


  }

  //........................................

  $('#dataForm').submit(function( event ) {
            if ($('#dataForm').valid()){
                $('#dataForm').hide();
                $('.processing.data.form').show();
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessUpdate).recordData(this);
            }
            event.preventDefault();
    });
    //...................................................
    function onSuccessUpdate(response){
      var numCols = joined.getNumberOfColumns();
      for (var i=0; i<numCols; i++){
          for (var key in response.form){
            if (!response.form.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
            if (joined.getColumnProperty(i, 'ident') == key){
                joined.setValue(response.row, i, response.form[key]);
            }
          }
      }
      tableChart.draw();//This should be updating the values!
      $('.message.success').html(response.message).show();
      $('#dataForm').show();
      $('.processing.data.form').hide();
      $('#userProfileDialog').dialog('close');
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any insights.  This one is driving me crazy.

Comment: Maybe the chartWrapper has the right dataTable/dataView references, but does not register the change for some reason. Maybe try `chartWrapper.getChart().draw(chartWrapper.getDataTable(), options)`? My one-liner is untested but I think you get the idea...

Comment: Or maybe you need to redraw the dashboard instead of the chart?

Comment: @nbering Neither works.  Both trigger a re-draw, but the displayed values themselves remain unchanged even though all values in dataTables and dataViews are updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that everything is working exactly as it should and the issue was in fact that I missed a critical facet of how this works.

When updating the joined dataTable values in the loop, I was was updating the 'value' using the setValue() method.

However, the 'value' that the rendered chart is actually reading is the 'formatted value' accessible through the setFormattedValue() method.  When updating the value programatically, there doesn't seem to be an automatic update to the formattedValue. I may have incorrectly assumed that or, more likely, have just been completely ignorant to that portion of it since I didn't use it.

Originally, prior to using the join when I only used a single data source and all was working, I was passing the 'options no_format' parameter to the query.  In that context, it seems that the API would use the value instead of the formattedValue for the actual table chart.

Once I realised my error, my first attempt at a fix was to add the 'options no_format' parameter to both of my data queries.  This didn't seem to work.  It looks like the join method automatically generates formatted values even if it's source dataTables don't have any.

Therefore, the correction to the my original code is to use the setFormattedValue method in addition to the setValues method as follows:

```
function onSuccessUpdate(response){
      var numCols = joined.getNumberOfColumns();
      for (var i=0; i<numCols; i++){
          for (var key in response.form){
            if (!response.form.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
            if (joined.getColumnProperty(i, 'ident') == key){
                joined.setValue(response.row, i, response.form[key]);
                //Need to also set formatted value
                joined.setFormattedValue(response.row, i, response.form[key]);
            }
          }
      }
      tableChart.draw();//This should be updating the values!
      $('.message.success').html(response.message).show();
      $('#dataForm').show();
      $('.processing.data.form').hide();
      $('#userProfileDialog').dialog('close');
```

Once both the value and formatted value are updated, the chart updates as expected on draw.

So in the end, this was simply a mistake on my part, but I hope there might be some value to someone with this example code and this particular behaviour of the dataTable generated by the join method.